# Unable to load large pandas dataframe to pyspark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, pyarrow

I've been trying to join two large pandas dataframes using pyspark using the following code. I'm trying to vary executor cores allocated for the application and measure scalability of pyspark (strong scaling).

```py
r = 1000000000 # 1Bn rows 
it = 10
w = 256
unique = 0.9

TOTAL_MEM = 240
TOTAL_NODES = 14

max_val = r * unique
rng = default_rng()
frame_data = rng.integers(0, max_val, size=(r, 2)) 
frame_data1 = rng.integers(0, max_val, size=(r, 2)) 
print(f"data generated", flush=True)

df_l = pd.DataFrame(frame_data).add_prefix("col")
df_r = pd.DataFrame(frame_data1).add_prefix("col")
print(f"data loaded", flush=True)


procs = int(math.ceil(w / TOTAL_NODES))
mem = int(TOTAL_MEM*0.9)
print(f"world sz {w} procs per worker {procs} mem {mem} iter {it}", flush=True)

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName(f'join {r} {w}')\
    .master('spark://node:7077')\
    .config('spark.executor.memory', f'{int(mem*0.6)}g')\
    .config('spark.executor.pyspark.memory', f'{int(mem*0.4)}g')\
    .config('spark.cores.max', w)\
    .config('spark.driver.memory', '100g')\
    .config('sspark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled', 'true')\
    .getOrCreate()

sdf0 = spark.createDataFrame(df_l).repartition(w).cache()
sdf1 = spark.createDataFrame(df_r).repartition(w).cache()
print(f"data loaded to spark", flush=True)

try:           
    for i in range(it):
        t1 = time.time()
        out = sdf0.join(sdf1, on='col0', how='inner')
        count = out.count()
        t2 = time.time()
        print(f"timings {r} {w} {i} {(t2 - t1) * 1000:.0f} ms, {count}", flush=True)
        
        del out
        del count
        gc.collect()
finally:
    spark.stop()
```

**Cluster**:
I am using standalone spark cluster in a 15 node cluster with 48 cores and 240GB RAM each. I've spawned master and the driver code in node1, while other 14 nodes have spawned workers allocating maximum memory.
In the spark context, I am reserving 90% of total memory to executor, splitting 60% to jvm and 40% to pyspark.

**Issue**:
When I run the above program, I can see that the executors are being assigned to the app. But it doesn't move forward, even after 60 mins. For smaller row count (10M), this was working without a problem.
Driver output

```
world sz 256 procs per worker 19 mem 216 iter 8
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
22/08/26 14:52:22 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
/N/u/d/dnperera/.conda/envs/cylonflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py:425: UserWarning: createDataFrame attempted Arrow optimization because 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled' is set to true; however, failed by the reason below:
  Negative initial size: -589934400
Attempting non-optimization as 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.fallback.enabled' is set to true.
  warn(msg)
```

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: May I know why you declare `it` = 10 but = 8 in your log?

Comment: Oh. I've taken it from the same code but on a run with 8 iterations :-) This fails in the first iteration. So, we havent even reached that point.